# how to add java.lang.Long to GroovyScript used for testing

Tags: java, spring, groovy, junit

I have an groovy script file which builds my test cases in my Spring application. Script looks like these:

```
 import com.productsell.model.UserRole;

 user2=builder.user([userId:2,username:"admin",password:"admin",email:"admin@productsell.com",userRole:UserRole.EMPLOYEE])
 user3=builder.user([userId:3,username:"korisnik1",password:"12345",email:"korisnik1@productsell.com",userRole:UserRole.CUSTOMER])
 user4=builder.user([userId:4,username:"korisnik2",password:"222proba",email:"korisnik2@productsell.com",userRole:UserRole.CUSTOMER])

 userList = [user2, user3, user4] as List
```

In my model class, userId property is type java.lang.Long, and when i run junit test, my test case won't find any user by id, so is there any way how to write value for java.lang.Long in groovy script?

Answer (score 1):

Add `l` or `L` to your numbers:

```
assert Long == 42l.class
assert Long == 42L.class
```